# Unusually large file size of recorded video

Tags: video, video-recording

The videos I record on my phone are significantly bigger in size than videos of similar or higher quality that my friends seem to record. I've tried to change the settings but to no avail. I'm currently using a resolution of 640*480 and have set the quality to normal (there is also fine and super fine). It's still taking up about 15 MB per minute. I've asked some friends and their videos are between 4 and 5 MB per minute and they're using similar or better settings.

What can I do to fix this and reduce the file size?

I have a [Huawei Ascend Y300](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ascend_y300-5386.php) running Android 4.1.

Comment: May I know what's the format of the video? Is there any setting for the frame rate?

Comment: It's an mp4 file. I'm not sure how to check the frame rate. Will keep looking but it's not in the file details.

Answer (score 1):

Video record size depends not only on resolution and framerate but also on the compression algorithm - the encoder used by your phone.

I suggest you transfer a video recorded with your phone and another recorded with your friend's phone to a computer and analyze them a bit with [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo).

[image]

Look for format, width, height, framerate and bitrate (probably the video quality setting affects bitrate) and if there are small differences between the two files then there may be a problem.

Comment: I don't seem to have as much info as you, but it's still useful. Here is [my video](http://i.imgur.com/OTRMC1u.png) and here is [my friend's](http://i.imgur.com/T2RzWzj.png). I use a different ratio and also use 1924 Kbps as opposed to 450. The bit rate is also substantially higher, obviously. The quality doesn't seem different though. I seem to be using a different Baseline. Any idea what that is?

Comment: @duxk.gh You have the same amount of information if you go to **View** and select **HTML**. Obviously, the bitrate is making the difference. It's more than 4 times greater which justifies the file size.

Comment: Oh right, thanks. And yes the bitrate seems to be the issue. I'm trying to see if there is any way to reduce that but so far haven't found anything.